# Is there such a C++ optimisation?

Tags: c++, optimization

E.g.

```
vector<string> a;

vector<string> b;

a.push_back("first");

b=a;
```

Would it be optimised somehow as

```
vector<string> b;

b.push_back("first");
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: Yes.

Long answer: Not really an "optimization", as most *modern* compilers (read as: non-MSVC) will do that. It's called [static single assignment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form) (SSA) and GCC supports it since version 4.0 - and it kicks ass, too!

Comment: I am surprised that you do not call it an optimisation.

Comment: I believe the term "optimization" has many, many vague definitions. I believe this type of "optimization" is better to be called "correction".

Comment: SSA doesn't automatically apply here. It is typically applied to primitive datatypes (or just on registers), but in high-level C++ code, assignments and constructors might have side effects, so the compiler has to check that it is safe to optimize away. And yes, then it is definitely an optimization.

Comment: Just to add weight to the opinion that GCC does not do this and to confirm that the MS compiler absolutely will not (I looked at disassembly to check, very easy, breakpoint and right click) it takes a lot of work for compiler to know a constructor, assignment, or pretty much anything has no side effects, in general it won't even try to find out. From what I know SSA applies at the register level - depending on your platform not even primitive types will benefit.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're saving yourself a call to `operator=`...

You should always remember the 2 rules of optimization though.

“The First Rule of Program Optimization: Don't do it. The Second Rule of Program Optimization (for experts only!): Don't do it yet.” - Michael A. Jackson

Comment: I hate that catchphrase, people who never worked with embedded systems have the luxury of working on fast machines that become sloppy and believe the compiler will do their job for them. Please read http://www.liranuna.com/sse-intrinsics-optimizations-in-popular-compilers/ so you can see how bad compilers can be sometimes.

Comment: Optimization is GOOD - just not in large quantities. Don't spend too much time on optimization but don't leave a program unoptimized. Just like a healthy diet, people NEED sweets in their life, even though it's considered "BAD" to consume.

Comment: +1 to LiraNuna. These rules of software optimization are nonsense (I wonder how many adepts they have...)! It should be "Learn to optimize", but not "Don't optimize".

Comment: I'd go with "Measure before you optimize: the bottleneck won't always be where you expect it."

Comment: I've spent a lot of time writing embedded code. It's true: Don't optimize!

Comment: This should concern micro-optimizations. It does not mean: Do not consider performance at all when choosing data structures, algorithms, ... In particular, OP is asking if he can rely on this rule when making larger-scale decisions, because if it turns out that the compiler is not smart enough, he might end up with lots of needless copying which could have been avoided by thinking a bit more about the program design. (IMO, you can get the design so wrong, that you just can't optimize the bottlenecks later without major redesigning.)